# Is there a way to export the variable in a ForEach loop to my CSV output on each line

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to run a script against our AD that spits out the AD Users in a group, for all the groups in a list. Essentially attempting to audit the groups to find the users. I have a functioning script, except I have no way to determine when the output of one group ends, and where the output of the next begins.

I have tried looking for previous examples, but nothing fits exactly the method I am using, and with me just dipping my toes into powershell I have not been able to combine other examples with my own.

```
$groups = Get-Content "C:\Folder\File_with_lines_of_ADGroup_Names.txt" 
foreach ($group in $groups) { Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$group" | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq "user" } | Get-ADUser -Property Description,DisplayName | Select Name,DisplayName,Description,$group | Export-csv -append -force -path "C:\Folder\File_of_outputs.csv" -NoTypeInformation }
```

Right now the problem lies with getting the $group variable to be exported along with the Name, DisplayName, and Description of each user returned. This is the best way I can think of to tag each user's group and keep all the results in a single file. However, only the first line of results works which is the HEADERS of the CSV, and everything after it is either listed as "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"or simply blank after the first group of results.

Hoping someone can show me how to easily add my variable $group to the output for each user found for filtering/pivoting purposes.

Thanks and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are after are calculated properties on your `select` statement.

```
Select Name,DisplayName,Description,$group
```

Should Probably be something like

```
Select Name,DisplayName,Description,@{n='Group'; e={$group};}
```

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/890559/powershell-calculated-properties-for-multiple-values

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I had seen similar syntax in my search for an answer, but had no idea what it was called and how to structure it for my needs.

Comment: Appreciate the answer as well as citation so I can learn and not just replicate.